# location of parameters in POST request

Tags: post

Is there any difference between putting parameters in the **url** and in the **request body** when using a **POST** request? I am testing some web interfaces, I find that no matter where I put my parameters, the server returns the right result. Can anyone help me explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your question may seem a tad bit broad, `I find that no matter where I put my parameters, the server returns the right result` is dependent on the web interfaces/Servers you are interacting with and their ability to handle such requests.

> By design, the POST request method requests that a web server accepts
>   and stores the data enclosed in the body of the request message. It
>   is often used when uploading a file or submitting a completed web
>   form.

In order to allow more flexibility there are APIs/Servers that will inspect the incoming request's body, headers and URL parameters for the information it needs to effectively map and serve the request.

If for example, a request was made and the values are sent in the request body with the content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so the request body uses the same format as a URL encoded query string:

```
POST http://path/to/resource
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 28

parameter=value&also=another
```

the same request could also be made without content and just a query string like

```
POST http://path/to/resource?parameter=value&also=another
Content-Length: 0
```

where the server may map it to the same resource as the previous request.

The same may not be true for a POST request to upload a file, which could more complicated and tends to use the `multipart/form-data` encoding instead, which has a different format.

According to the specifications, servers are expected to be tolerant in what they receive from clients and tend to be strict in what they return to clients.